# Parsing JSON as numeric - iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

My iphone app is accessing a JSON service which returns something like:

```
{"theResult":{"Total":1.5, "Comment":"some comment"}}
```

The code I'm using successfully parses any NSStrings such as the comment field above but I am having trouble with numeric values.

```
NSDictionary *res= [json objectForKey:@"theResult"];
NSString *comment = [res objectForKey:@"Comment"];
NSDecimal *total = (__bridge NSDecimal *)[res objectForKey:@"Total"];
```

The *total variable does not get set correctly and causes a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

How do I parse numeric values in objective-c?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

convert the object to the correct data type, like this

```
float total = [[res objectForKey:@"Total"] floatValue];
```

Comment: when i print this using nslog the value is 0.0000 rather than 1.5 so I don't think it's working

Comment: and which is the output of `NSLog` `[res objectForKey:@"Total"]`?

Comment: try this `NSLog(@"%@", [res objectForKey:@"Total"]);`

Comment: prints null. viewing the json result using a web browser the value is most definitely 1.5

Comment: which is the output of this NSLog(@"%@", res);

Comment: thanks for the tips, was looking in the wrong part of the json object, float is working properly

Answer (score 1):

just get `NSString *strtotal = [res objectForKey:@"Total"];` then convert what ever format do you want like

```
NSDecimalNumber *decimal = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:strtotal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following method

```
+(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberWithString:(NSString *)numericString in NSDecimalNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSDecimal` is not an object, it's an opaque struct. `NSDecimalNumber` is an object and what you'll want to cast to. Since both `id` and `NSDecimalNumber *` are object types, you don't need to use `__bridge`.

Additionally, the number in your JSON may not even be parsed into a decimal number; it could just be a float or a double (contained in an `NSNumber`).

Comment: have tried NSNumber *total = [res objectForKey:@"Total"] to no avail

Comment: What does this print? `NSLog(@"%@, %@", [res objectForKey:@"Total"], NSStringForClass([[res objectForKey:@"Total"] class]));`